# yii url duplicate with seo friendly and original url

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

I have a yii1 application. I create seo friendly urls and it works. However i can get all page with two url. Here is some example:

```
http://paintballshop.hu/index.php?r=news/index
```

or

```
http://paintballshop.hu/kozosseg
```

One more example:

```
http://paintballshop.hu/
```

or

```
http://paintballshop.hu/index.php
```

Google said: duplicate pages without a canonical tag. status: excluded
(and i dont have duplicate content)

This is my url manager:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(

                    'menu/<url>'=>'site/contentview',
                    'kozosseg'=>'news/index',
                    'kozossegi/<url>'=>'news/view',
                    'kapcsolat'=>'site/contact',
                    'uj-termekek'=>'site/latest',
                    '<url>'=>'products/view',
                    'paintball-termekek/<url>'=>'category/view',
                    ''=>'site/index',
    ),
),
```

And this is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.paintballshop\.hu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://paintballshop.hu/$1 [R=permanent,L] 

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: why? Its a coding question, not seo

Comment: its due the the problem you are facing